# gtk menu popup not showing when calling it inside a clutter actor?

Tags: menu, popup, gtk, vala, clutter

im trying to show a gtk menu popup when a Clutter Actor is right-clicked. For some reason, the menu is not showing. Here is my code (not all, only the handler)

```
button_press_event.connect((event) => {
    if (event.click_count < 2 && event.button == 1) {
        debug("Icon simple click\n");
} else if (event.click_count < 2 && event.button == 3) {
        debug("Showing Pop Up menu\n");
        var popup_menu = new PopupMenu();
        popup_menu.add_menu_item("Prueba 1");
        popup_menu.show_all();
        popup_menu.show_popup();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

PopupMenu is a litle wrapper of gtk.menu I did

```
public class PopupMenu : Gtk.Menu {

public PopupMenu.from_gtk_widget (Gtk.Widget parent) {

     parent.button_release_event.connect((event) => {
        if(event.button == 3) this.show_popup();
        return true;
    });

}


construct {

}

public Gtk.MenuItem add_menu_item (string label) {
    var item = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label(label);
    this.append (item);
    return item;
}

//Draw the popup at the mouse position
public void show_popup() {
    debug("Popup Showing\n");
    this.popup(null, null, null, 2, 0);
}
}
```

The actor is inside an actor with flowlayout. This actor is inside a gtk window which is transparent. Debug messages are shown.

Why is this not working? thanks

Comment: Create a minimal executable example, what you showed is barley useful to diagnose anything at all.